# Finding the limit when one part goes to infinity and the other part goes to zero

Tags: limits

Let's say you have a function $$f(x) = h(x)g(x)$$.  You know that $h(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, and  $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

How can you go about finding the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider $\lim \dfrac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{h(x)}}$, as now the numerator and denominator both go to 0. So now, you can use L'Hopital's rule if they are differentiable.

Comment: This won't work too well if, say, $h(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$, but I guess we have to let Angada work out some of the answer.

Comment: Very True.     ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with l'hopital's rule? If so, do you see how to rewrite your function so that it is in a form which meets the l'hopital hypotheses?